# <anonymous> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onFailure(int,Header[],byte[],Throwable) in AsyncHttpResponseHandler

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, abstract-class

Evening everyone. I REALLY need some help. I've had some issues in the past getting apps to compile but this current situation is nearly enough to make me want to NOT quit my day job.

I have an Android application that was running perfectly fine in eclipse. However, ever since the upgrade last week i have not been able to get it back running. Its been so bad that I decided to import the application to the Android Studio.

Now I have imported the application to Android studio,which i do like btw, and I have an error that I just can't seem to figure out.

If I compile the application w/o "android-async-http-1.4.5.jar" I get errors stating:

```
Error:(29, 30) error: package com.loopj.android.http does not exist
```

for each area in the app where there is an Async function is called. However, once I add "android-sync-http-1.4.5.jar" I get the following error throughout the app each time the function is called:

```
Error:(74, 104) error: <anonymous com.peekatucorp.peekatu.ChatActivity$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method onFailure(int,Header[],byte[],Throwable) in AsyncHttpResponseHandler
Error:(75, 13) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Please help. I dont know what Im missing.

```
ChatActivity.java

package com.peekatucorp.peekatu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import java.util.Random;
public class ChatActivity extends Activity {
    private com.peekatucorp.peekatu.DiscussArrayAdapter adapter;
    private ListView lv;
//  private LoremIpsum ipsum;
    private EditText editText1;
    private static Random random;
    private String selected_room;
    private String last_message;
    private Document responseDoc;
    @Override protected void onResume() { 
        super.onResume(); // setText() here 
        Log.v("response", "request");

        Intent i = this.getIntent();
        String type = i.getExtras().getString("type");
        Log.v("response ", "messages type "+type);
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))


        getChatMessages();
        else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
            getInboxMessages();
        else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("3"))
            getUserMessages(i.getExtras().getString("conv_user"));
    }
    public void getUserMessages(final String forUserID){
        final SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
        AsyncHttpClient  client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("action", "get");
         params.put("room", preferences.getString("selected_room", "Lobby"));
         params.put("dist", "0");
         params.put("pmsgid", "1");
         params.put("msgid", "9999999999999");
         params.put("private_toid", forUserID);
         params.put("webversion", "1");
         params.put("censor", "0");
         params.put("email", preferences.getString("loggedin_user", ""));
         /* pmsgid:906588*/

    ///  params.put("profile_picture", new File("pic.jpg")); // Upload a File
    //   params.put("profile_picture2", someInputStream); // Upload an InputStream
    //   params.put("profile_picture3", new ByteArrayInputStream(someBytes)); // Upload some bytes

        client.post("http://peekatu.com/apiweb/messagetest.php",params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String response) {
            //  Log.v("response", response);
                 XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();

                 Document doc = parser.getDomElement(response); // getting DOM element


                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("PMESSAGE");
                Log.v("response ", "messages count "+nl.getLength());
                // looping through all item nodes <item>
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                    // creating new HashMap

                    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
              //      Log.v("response ", "messages  "+parser.getValue(e, "TEXT"));
                   // adapter.add(new OneComment(true, "OKOKOK"));
                    Boolean dir = true;
                    if(!parser.getValue(e, "USERID").equalsIgnoreCase(forUserID)){
                        dir = true;
                    }
                    adapter.add(new OneComment(dir, 
                            parser.getValue(e, "TEXT"),
                            parser.getValue(e, "USERID"),
                            parser.getValue(e, "ALIAS"),
                            parser.getValue(e, "GENDER"),
                            parser.getValue(e, "PIC"),
                            parser.getValue(e, "TDATE"),
                            parser.getValue(e, "ONLINE"),
                            parser.getValue(e, "MSGPIC")));
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                   // menuItems.add(map);
                }
                lv.setSelection(adapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
    }
```

build.gradle

```
 build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'

    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.peekatucorp.peekatu"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0+'
    compile files('libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobclix.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.4-with-sources.jar')
    compile files('libs/urlimageviewhelper-1.0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.5.jar')
}
```

I need help. I have been trying to get this app to run again for the pass 72hrs. Someone please assist me. Thank you in advanced. I have read about every resource I could find online and now Im at a dead end.

Comment: Anyone? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: If you Google "is not abstract and does not override abstract method" it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Scott, I have. but I do not understand. Can some one assist me by explaining whats happening. I guess the answer is "easy" but I dont get it.

Comment: Android Studio should be giving you a red error underline under the "new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()" call. If you hover over it, you will get a tooltip with a similar but slightly more descriptive error message. Click on it. It will show a small icon with a red lightbulb. Click on that icon (or alternately, type alt-Enter) and it will offer you quickfixes to solve the problem.

Comment: Did you solve this?
I am having the same error but I am sure that I have correctly overrode the methods.

Answer (score 1):

You have just to replace `org.apache.http.Header` by `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header` in the success and failure methods header